# Errors in ARIMA models

Tags: arima

I want to fetch MAPE error of arima model after fitting model.
below is the summary of arima model

Series: train 
ARIMA(1,1,1)

Coefficients:
         ar1     ma1
      0.4472  -0.925
s.e.  0.0310   0.014

sigma^2 estimated as 211188552:  log likelihood=-14820.68
AIC=29647.36   AICc=29647.38   BIC=29662.98

Training set error measures:
                   ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE      MASE         ACF1
Training set 413.1383 14516.15 9886.802 -17.77737 27.93304 0.9202813 -0.008861643
 num [1, 1:7] 413.1 14516.1 9886.8 -17.8 27.9 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr "Training set"
  ..$ : chr [1:7] "ME" "RMSE" "MAE" "MPE" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
  mape_error<-accuracy(fit)
  mape_error<-data.frame(mape_error)
  mape<-mape_error$MAPE
```

Answer (score 0):

library(forecast)

This gets your point predictions, decide on an horizon(h) length
`pred <- forecast(fit, h = 3)$mean`

m_pred and actual(same length as h) have to be the same length
`MAPE <- accuracy(m_pred, actual)[5]

RMSE<- accuracy(m_pred, actual)[2]` 
etc.